# SFML texture holder deleted although still in scope

Tags: c++, oop, sfml

So I'm new to SFML. I read a lot of post, but I really  don't get it.
I wrote an texture holder:

```
class tile_texture_holder {
private:
    sf::Texture tx;
public:
    tile_texture_holder(type a) {
        switch (a) {
        case type::desert:
            tx.loadFromFile("C:/Users/Andreas/source/repos/conquer/Media/desert.png");
            break;
        case type::grass:
            tx.loadFromFile("C:/Users/Andreas/source/repos/conquer/Media/grass.png");
            break;
        case type::mountain:
            tx.loadFromFile("C:/Users/Andreas/source/repos/conquer/Media/mountain.png");
            break;
        case type::water:
            tx.loadFromFile("C:/Users/Andreas/source/repos/conquer/Media/water.png");
            break;
        }
    }
    sf::Texture ret_texture() {
        return tx;
    }

    ~tile_texture_holder() {
        std::cout << "///////////////////////HOLDER DELETED!!!/////////////////////" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

And I tried to load a sprite with it in different ways....

For example:

```
tile_texture_holder t(type::desert);
        sf::Sprite s; 
        s.setTexture(t.ret_texture());
```

(in the same function, where I draw the sprite)

I always get the white box being drawn. And I really dont get why the texture_holder is getting deleted.

BTW type is an enum.

I hope somebody can help me solve my issue!

Answer (score 1):

```
s.setTexture(t.ret_texture());
```

in the line above you have undefined behaviour.

`ret_texture` returns temporary texture (it is returned by value, so a copy is made), `setTexture` takes reference to it, then at the end of expression temporary texture is destroyed and you have dangling reference in `s`.

Why this happens? Because `setTexture` of `Sprite` only holds reference to texture, it doesn't copy it.

According to [SFML Sprite reference](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Sprite.php#a3729c88d88ac38c19317c18e87242560):

> The texture argument refers to a texture that must exist as long as
>   the sprite uses it. Indeed, the sprite doesn't store its own copy of
>   the texture, but rather keeps a pointer to the one that you passed to
>   this function.

Solution: `ret_texture` should return texture by reference.

```
sf::Texture& ret_texture() {
    return tx;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed tx to public to solve this issue. I tried declaring *tx instead of tx before and returning the pointer but the destructor was still being called. (I still don't know why)